# Ignoring Blank Cells when converting from Hex to Decimal in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, hex, decimal

I am new to VBA and have a small doubt. I was trying to convert certain values from a particular cell from hexadecimal to decimal, I have a small difficulty in that. In that cell there are lot of blank cells. For example the first 5 rows are blank then I have a hex value again 3 blank rows and a hex value. I am not able to loop through due to the blank cell. Please if somebody could help. Below is the code I wrote.

```
Sub Conversion()

Dim j As Integer
Dim LR As Integer

LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 3 To LR
If Cells(j, 2).value = "" Then Cells(j, 3).value = "#N/A" Else
Cells(j, 3).value = CLng("&H" & Cells(j, 2).value)


Next
End Sub
```

I am getting Mismatch error with this code

Answer (score 1):

You kinda forgot `End If` at the end. I have organized your code little bit and add `End If` and seems it works.

```
Sub Conversion()

Dim j As Integer
Dim LR As Integer

LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

MsgBox Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 3 To LR
If Cells(j, 2).Value = "" Then
    Cells(j, 3).Value = "#N/A"
Else
    Cells(j, 3).Value = CLng("&H" & Cells(j, 2).Value)
End If

Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

CLng is not working, as it is giving error in that as far as i read and understood you can use the below code, YOu can use Format instead of the CLNG command in ur code

```
Sub Conversion()

Dim j As Integer
Dim LR As Integer

LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 1 To LR
If Cells(j, 1).Value = "" Then
    Cells(j, 3).Value = "#N/A"
Else
    Cells(j, 3).Value = "&H" & Format(Cells(j, 1).Value, "0")
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For j = 3 To LR
If Cells(j, 2).Value = "" Then
  Cells(j, 3).Value = "#N/A"
Else
  Cells(j, 3).Value = CLng("&H" & Cells(j, 2).Value)
End If
```

For ignoring errors:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick response it was of great help!!

Answer (score 0):

here is one that uses a ternary function

```
Sub Conversion()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

    Dim LR As Range
    Set LR = sht.Range("B1", sht.Range("B" & sht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In LR

        cel.Offset(0, 1).Value = IIf(cel.Value = "", "#N/A", CLng("&H" & cel.Value))

    Next cel
End Sub
```